# PHP static analysis: define method return from object template based on parameter value

Tags: php, templates, generics, static-analysis, template-specialization

This might be tricky to describe, which is why I'm struggling to find matching answers.

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

/**
 * @template T of object{'a': string, 'b': int, 'c': DateTime}
 */
class Foo {
    /**
     * @var object<T>
     */
    private object $foo;

    // Assume __construct populates the $foo property

    /**
     * @param key-of<T> doesn't seem to apply here - only applies
     *                  to catching keys that aren't in T
     *
     * @return ??? indicate $key is a property of T, so return is that property's type
     */
    public function get(string $key)
    {
        return $this->foo->{$key};
    }
}

function string_only(string $a): string { return $a; }
function integer_only(int $b): int { return $b; }

// How do I know what was returned?
$a = (new Foo)->get('a');
// $a should be treated as string by code analysis
string_only($a);  // OK
integer_only($a); // Inspection type warning

$b = (new Foo)->get('b');
// $b should be treated as int by code analysis
string_only($b);  // Inspection type warning
integer_only($b); // OK

$c = (new Foo)->get('c');
// Code completion should know I can do this
$c->format('Ymd');
```

***PhpStorm*** inspection results of various attempts:

```
// @return T<$key>
// @return T{$key}
string_only($a); // "Return value must be of type 'string', 'object' returned"

// @return T->$key
string_only($a); // "Return value must be of type 'string', 'T-' returned"
```

Various other attempts aren't recognized as anything or gave similar to above.

Can this be done with any of the current PHP SA tools?

---

I tried various patterns in the `@return` annotation but inspections either didn't recognize them at all, or indicated the function returns an object rather than the type of the object's key.

I was hoping to have static analysis tools understand that the value of `$key` represents a property of the `T` object.